# How can I allow any character in a regular expression?

Tags: regex

Currently, I use the following regular expression for the user to enter a password

```
^\w{8,16}$
```

Now as I understand, \w only allows a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and the _ character (underscore). I want to do allow *any* character, but the length is to be between 8 and 16. How do I get about doing it?

Comment: Why do you need to use regex? I'm sure in whatever language you're using there's a char count function that will count the length of your string.

Comment: You are absolutely right Joe! So I would actually require RegEx only if there is a situation where certain characters should NOT be in the password etc correct?

Comment: Yes, regex is a very powerful match, replace tool for manipulating strings. All that you seem to want is something to count chars. Btw, u can use .{8,16} to match any chars

Comment: you could also use a regex (or more than one regex) to enforce a complexity requirement - e.g. "must include a number and a letter" might be (in addition to a normal char count) `[A-Za-z].*[0-9]|[0-9].*[A-Za-z]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, use a word count for what you need rather than regex.

If you really must, then `.{8,16}` should work, the `.` matches a single char, no matter what it is.

EDIT:
To preempt your next question which will surely be, what is a good password validation regular expression, you might want to check out some of these blogs:

http://nilangshah.wordpress.com/2007/06/26/password-validation-via-regular-expression/

http://www.zorched.net/2009/05/08/password-strength-validation-with-regular-expressions/

OR just look up 'password validation stackoverflow' on google

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
^.{8,16}$
```

The dot matches a single character, without caring what that character is. The only exception are newline characters. By default, the dot will not match a newline character.

For the details, please visit *[The Dot Matches (Almost) Any Character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)*.