# How do I create a regular expression of minimum 8, maximum 16, alphabetic, numbers and NO space?

Tags: regex

I am trying to check text with a regular expression in iOS, and below is my code. My regular expression is accepting one word or number which it should be minimum 8 and maximum 16 with numbers or alphabetic.

```
if (![self validate:txtPass.text regex:@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"]){

   NSLOG(@"Check value");
}
```

What should I change in my regular expression?

Comment: please **stop now** if you're planning to use this for password validation. limiting the maximum length of a password makes no sense and it's a very bad idea from a security standpoint. instead, only check for the minimum length (see one of the examples in the accepted answer).

Comment: @szaman: Such a maximum could be imposed by an external system (though such a limit should not be revealed voluntarily). Some banks have been known to only use 8 characters (due to limitations in old mainframe backend systems). I wouldn't be surprised if that is still the case for some banks.

Comment: Or maybe it is just a common homework assignment. Here is another one with a 8,16 requirement: *[How can I allow any character in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953463/how-to-allow-any-character-in-regex)*

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,16}$`

You can specify the minimum/maximum gathered using {X,Y} as the boundaries.

Other examples:
`^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}$`  #8 or more characters
`^[a-zA-Z0-9]{,16}$` #Less than or equal to 16 characters
`^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}$`   #Exactly 8 characters

[Regex cheatsheet](http://krijnhoetmer.nl/stuff/regex/cheat-sheet/)

Comment: but while the user is typing, and suddenly change the scope out of the line edit, the line Edit will have the incomplete 8 characters, so how can one overcame this i.e. how can one delete the incomplete input?

Comment: Less than or equal is not working.

^[a-zA-Z0-9]{,16}$

. Check the link to test:

https://regex101.com/r/oE3rP4/3

Answer (score 4):

You just need to put bounds on, not the + (one or more) operator.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,16}$
```

Answer (score 2):

`^[A-Za-z0-9]{8,16}$`

Specify a min/max length for a part of an expression using `{x,y}`, where `x` is the minimum and `y` is the maximum.

Comment: the link is not working, here is a valid one : https://krijnhoetmer.nl/stuff/regex/cheat-sheet/

Answer (score -4):

```
^[A-Za-z0-9_@].{4,8}$
```

You can check your condition from here: 
https://regex101.com/r/rqedfJ/1

Comment: This answer is clearly wrong. The fact that it times out on Regex101.com is a symptom of that. Why post a new answer to an old question with several highly-voted answers anyway?